# PinnedDispatcher is not working (Akka 2.2-M3)

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to Akka and I am trying to work through the getting started series. I was able to get a Dispatcher configured, and now I am trying to get a PinnedDispatcher configured. I do what the getting started page instructs, but I get the error message

```
[WARN] [06/19/2013 12:53:13.791] [System-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [akka.actor.my-pinned-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
```

Here is the scala code:

```
val system = ActorSystem("System")
val a = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor].withDispatcher("akka.actor.my-pinned-dispatcher")) //this doesnt work

val a = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor].withDispatcher("akka.actor.my-dispatcher")) //this does work

a ! "Hello World"

system.shutdown()

class TestActor extends Actor {
def receive = {
    case s: String => println(s)
}
}
```

and here is my application.conf

```
akka {
actor {
    my-pinned-dispatcher {
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        type = PinnedDispatcher
    }

    my-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher

        executor = "fork-join-executor"

        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-min = 2

            parallelism-factor = 2.0

            parallelism-max = 10
        }

        throughput = 100
    }
}
}
```

Did I configure the PinnedDispatcher wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing this issue. I pulled down 2.2-M3 and ran your code and it worked correctly.  Can you include the actual code as this is just a bunch of pieces of code and maybe the issue is in something that's not shown here.

Comment: The one source file: http://pastebin.com/jezNFTnh

The config file: http://pastebin.com/j7CFbG3J

Comment: what about classpath? are you sure application.conf is under classpath?